# Optimize - Function that SELECTs from TEMP TABLE within loop to get averages of JSON values

Tags: mysql, json, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a Mysql Function that runs as part of a larger query reading a few million records. In order to detect anomalies, I'm figuring out the average change over time. The data in the table is stored as JSON objects with UNIX timestamps as the key for up to 30 days.

As an example, the input (input_array) would look something like:

```
[{"1532944806": 16}, {"1533031206": 14}, {"1533117605": 13}, {"1533204305": 12}, {"1533290708": 10}, {"1533463506": 9}, {"1533549907": 9}, {"1533636306": 9}, {"1533722707": 9}, {"1533809108": 9}, {"1533895506": 9}, {"1533981906": 8}, {"1534068306": 7}, {"1534154706": 7}, {"1534241108": 7}, {"1534590304": 7}, {"1534673106": 12}, {"1534759508": 6}, {"1534845905": 7}, {"1534932306": 7}, {"1535018707": 5}, {"1535105106": 3}, {"1535191505": 7}, {"1535277907": 6}, {"1535364305": 7}, {"1535450706": 2}, {"1535537107": 1}]
```

I'm only looking to average **decreasing** changes - not any change that increases over a day.

I'm checking that a value for the previous day exists, and if so, I'm calculating change and adding it into a temporary table that gets queried at to select the average.

So far I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `daily_averages`(input_array JSON) RETURNS int(4)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE array_length INTEGER(2);
    DECLARE prev_value INTEGER(4);
    DECLARE idx INTEGER(4);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS collection;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE collection (change INTEGER(4) SIGNED DEFAULT 0);

    SELECT JSON_LENGTH(input_array) INTO array_length;

    SET idx = 0;

    WHILE idx < array_length DO

        SELECT 

        IF(idx-1 > -1,
            CONVERT(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        JSON_EXTRACT( input_array, CONCAT( '$[', idx-1, ']' ) )
                        , '$.*'
                    )
                    , '$[0]'
                ), SIGNED INTEGER
            ) 
            , -1
        )

        INTO prev_value;


        INSERT INTO collection
        SELECT (prev_value - 
            (
                CONVERT(
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        JSON_EXTRACT(
                            JSON_EXTRACT( input_array, CONCAT( '$[', idx, ']' ) )
                            , '$.*'
                        )
                        , '$[0]'
                    ), SIGNED INTEGER
                )
            )
       )
       FROM DUAL
       WHERE prev_value > 0;

       SET idx = idx + 1;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN (SELECT AVG(change) FROM collection WHERE change > -1);

END
```

With about 2.7 million records, it takes about 20 minutes to run currently. I'm looking to optimize this or re-write it by avoiding the DROP/CREATE overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unnecessary to create a table just to calculate an average, it's simple to do in the loop. Instead of inserting each value into a table, add it to a total variable. At the end, return `total/count`.

Since you're totalling the differences between values,

You can also use `SET` statements to assign variables, rather than `SELECT ... INTO variable`.

```
DECLARE array_length INTEGER(2);
DECLARE prev_value INTEGER(4);
DECLARE idx INTEGER(4);
DECLARE total INTEGER(4);
DECLARE counter INTEGER(4);
DECLARE cur_value INTEGER(4);

SET array_length = JSON_LENGTH(input_array);
SET total = 0;
SET counter = 0;
-- Initialize prev_value to the first element
SET prev_value = CONVERT(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        JSON_EXTRACT( input_array, '$[0]' )
                        , '$.*'
                    )
                    , '$[0]'
                ), SIGNED INTEGER
            );
SET idx = 1;

WHILE idx < array_length DO
    SET cur_value = CONVERT(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        JSON_EXTRACT( input_array, CONCAT( '$[', idx, ']' ) )
                        , '$.*'
                    )
                    , '$[0]'
                ), SIGNED INTEGER
            );
    IF cur_value < prev_value
    THEN
        SET total = total + (prev_value - cur_value);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END IF;
    SET prev_value = cur_value;
    SET idx = idx + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN total / counter;
```

Comment: prev_value must be inside the loop. It's not the first value of the array, it's the previous value to the current. But otherwise, this may work. WIll test.

Comment: The loop starts at `idx = 1`, so the first array element is the initial `prev_value`.

Comment: That way, the loop doesn't need `IF` statements to special-case the first iteration, when `prev_value` isn't set yet.

Comment: Ahh. Yes. Now I see. Smart.

Comment: I'll accept this answer once the edits have been accepted.

Comment: I added the missing `idx` increment. I don't see the need to cast the return type to `UNSIGNED`, since the function is declared as returning `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Digging inside a million JSON strings.  I'm amazed it took *only* 20 minutes.

As you *insert* the rows, do some calculations and store the results somewhere.  Then use *that* for doing the monitoring.

Even if you can't do it as you insert the rows, do it only to the 'new' rows.  Again save the previous info somewhere.

As for DROP/CREATE...  That can be sped up by having a permanent table, then use only `TRUNCATE TABLE` at the start of each proc call.

The `(4)` in `INTEGER(4)` does not mean anything.  You will always get a 32-bit integer.  (This note probably has no impact on the proc.)